# Subversion: Adding files to the project

Tags: svn

I am using library xyz where the files exists in folder xyz, and I want to update the files (eg. a upgrade to a new version), can I just copy the new xyz folder into my project using the file browser? The folder has both files and directories.

/Subversion noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. What you'll miss though, is if there are any files deleted in the upgraded version. To get around that, you'd want to first delete all the files from the svn working copy, then copy the new files in. Missing files can then be assumed to be deleted and added plus modified files will be picked up.

Note that when deleting the files from the working copy, you need to leave directories and their `.svn` subdirectories in place. Removing any resultant empty directories after the upgrade is left as an exercise. :)

Comment: this is the right approach -- also you will need to manually add any files that are new in the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

if xyz is already added to the repository and then you overwrite the files with an upgrade then svn status will show modifications in your xyz folder. Test the app after the upgrade and if everything is fine commit the changes.